# Examples of steady play in Go games?

Tags: go

I am looking for examples of professional Go games where one of the pros played solid, steady moves that were initially considered slow by the commentators, but eventually won him/her the game.

My objective is to try and better understand the role of reinforcement moves.

Thanks!

Comment: As to specific games, I think someone else might be able to point you exactly, but if we want to talk about players, I recommend Kobayashi Koichi, or Lee Changho. The former because of his very territorial style of play, the latter because of the thick, endgame approach.

Comment: Notably, Alpha Go moves were initially considered either slow or mistakes. In reality the bot was maximizing its probability of winning rather than maximizing its score. The bot's goal was to win even if it was by 0.5 moku.

Answer (score 2):

[Michael Redmond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Redmond_(Go_player)), the only western nine-dan pro, is a player who plays in the style you describe. The result is that he has placed "high" in several tournaments but has never won one. He "outlasts" most players but inevitably falls to one with a "sharper" style. His games (and game commentaries) often serve as models for the kind of play you are looking for.[Here](http://www.usgo.org/news/2010/06/michael-redmond-on-studying-improving-your-game-and-how-the-pros-train/) is some Redmond commentary. And here are some of his [games](http://ps.waltheri.net/database/player/Michael%20Redmond/)

It has been noted by a commenter that the computer program Alpha Go plays "slow" moves that maximizes the chances of winning, rather than maximizing the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout games of Minoru Kitani, Hideo Otake, or Rin Kaiho.